# What is Spring's Minimum Dependencies for Dependency Injection?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

What are the minimum dependencies required to just use Spring's dependency injection (core framework only)?  I'm using Spring for a standalone application, and I'd like to minimize the number of dependencies that I have to ship with the application.

I suppose I could systematically remove a Jar and see if the application breaks, but it would be much better if someone had a definitive answer.

Oh, and I'm using Spring 2.5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the `readme.txt` that comes with the download of Spring 2.5.

Assuming you don't have AOP, JDBC, Transactions, or ORM, then your best bet is probably:

- spring-core
- spring-beans
- spring-context

Comment: Thanks.  The readme.txt clearly lists the dependencies for the spring jars.  Looks like I can get away with just the three jars you mentioned, plus Commons Logging.

Comment: @toolkit, what if i want to use beside the DI, the messagesSource,PropertyPlaceHolder and Hibernate/JDBC support.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using maven then only spring-context is needed in your pom.xml, it depends on aop, beans, core, expression and asm