# Minimum JARs for Spring 3.0 dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-3

Similarly to [this question regarding an earlier Spring version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877312/what-is-springs-minimum-dependencies-for-dependency-injection), what are the minimum dependencies required for an application to use Spring **3.0** dependency injection only?  The application context will be configured by XML only.  Spring depends on a logging framework, so assume I already include these JARs for logging:

- jcl-over-slf4j.jar
- logback-classic.jar
- logback-core.jar
- slf4j-api.jar

Comment: I sure hope any of these logging jars get declared as runtime dependencies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As stated in another answer, maven is the true path.  If; however, you choose to stray, then based on section "1.2.1 Core Container" of the
[Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) I believe these to be the minimum jars for core spring functionality:

- org.springframework.asm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.context-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.expression-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar

Edited: sorted the list, using wiki formatting.

Updated for Spring 3.2:  It seems that asm is not part of the 3.2 distribution.  Below is the list for Spring 3.2:

- spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-expression-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

Comment: I never used Maven and I'm [not inclined to start](http://dustin.github.com/2010/04/01/why-not-maven.html).  By adding one JAR at a time until a tiny test application can load a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, I came up with the same Spring modules you listed but with org.springframework.asm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar as an additional run-time dependency.  If you edit your answer to add this JAR, I will accept the answer.

Comment: I know I'm late to this little party, but thank you -- this has always been one of my main stumbling blocks for using Spring for anything other than a web project; it's an awesome framework, but I hate the fact that it's so huge and there's such little documentation on what libraries are required for what feature.

Comment: RE: `...asm.jar`: See **D.3 Inlining of spring-asm jar** section at [http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/migration-3.2.html]

Comment: Does that mean without above four jars, dependency injection can not be achieved? am i correct?

Answer (score 5):

the best - and reliable way - of establishing this is to create a maven project and add dependency for spring-core, spring-bundle and spring-context. when you build/install this project maven will do the needful.

Comment: Just because the jar is included by Maven doesn't mean you always need it. I usually end up excluding some jars manually, especially commons-logging now that I use slf4j.

Answer (score 0):

YMMV, but I'd do the following:

First, import the Spring BOM in the dependency management section, to ensure a baseline dependency version:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
     </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
```

Then, in the build/dependency section, import beans, context and core, and EL if you plan to configure Spring via xml configuration (or using test scope if you only plan to use Spring xml configuration for your tests harness.)

**Note:** This example is with 3.2.x. If you need to use Spring before 3.2.x, you will need to include asm explicitly. One possibility is to use a profile activated only for Spring versions below 3.2.x.

```
<build>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <!-- inlines asm since 3.2.x -->
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope><!-- or compile/provided if used beyond testing -->
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</build>
```