# Downloading Spring Framework release 3.2

Tags: spring, download

Currently, I'm looking at the [springsource community download](http://www.springsource.org/download/community) site.

It shows that **3.2.4** is the latest general release. Its zip file has `dist` suffix and the content is different than the latest in 3.1 branch **3.1.4** (which does not have `dist` ending).

3.1.4 has the following directories:

- dist
- projects
- src

**dist** folder contains `org.springframework...*` jars.

3.2.4 has the following directories:

- docs
- libs
- schema

**lib** folder contains `spring-...` jars

Was there a major change between `3.1` and `3.2` releases?

According to [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053981/minimum-jars-for-spring-3-0-dependency-injection) there was but I was not able to find anything about it.

Does anybody have any particulars?

Should I get 3.1.4 for now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a spring source decision to change it. (I think there was an blog article somewhere, but I can`t found it)

> The distribution archive for release 3.2 RC1 is called spring-3.2.0.RC1-dist.zip; whereas, all releases prior to 3.2 generated distribution archives called spring-framework-*-dist.zip.

It is not a bug, it is not a major change in the code, and I highly doubt that they will switch back to the old layout (so there is no reason to stay with 3.1.4).

For the changes: have a look at the feature list and change log:

- http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.2.html
- http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/changelog.txt

Comment: Thank you. So they renamed zip files, changed their structure, deprecated `org.springframework...*` in favor of new `spring-... `.  As far as files (not features) are concerned, have I missed something?

Comment: I strongly recommend to use maven.

Comment: +1 to @Ralph's point. Anybody building Spring project without a dependency management tool such as Maven or Gradle is clearly a masochist. :)

Comment: Maven is great. Except, the client doesn't use it. Oh, snap!